# When does HikariCP idleTimeout default value apply?

Tags: spring-boot, connection-pooling, jdbctemplate, hikaricp

In the HikariCP [documentation](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#frequently-used), under idleTimeout is says that:
**This setting only applies when minimumIdle is defined to be less than maximumPoolSize**.

What happens if this property ***does not apply***?

Does it mean that the idle connections will never close (as long as they are less than maxLifetime ms)?
Or Does it mean that the idle connections WILL close, but after the default value i.e. 10 minutes?[image]

Comment: They will never close as there is no idle checking being done if `minimumIdle` is greater or equal to `maximumPoolSize`.

Comment: That is what I figured. Just needed confirmation. Thanks for clarifying.